# How to fix str object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, forms-authentication

I am migrating my model in Django project but error is being generated.Below is the code. What should be corrections in my code to solve this

```
Models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    #addtional
    portfolio_site = models.URLField(blank=True)

    profile_pic = models.ImageField(blank=True,upload_to="profile_pics")

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.user.username)
```

```
Forms.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from basic_app.models import UserProfileInfo

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = User.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email', 'password']


class UserProfileInfo(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = UserProfileInfo
        fields=['portfolio_site','profile_pic']
```

```
Admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from basic_app.models import UserProfileInfo


# Register your models here.
admin.site.register('UserProfileInfo')
```

I am getting
 Attribute Error: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: Reading the FineManual might help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.register

Answer (score 2):

The parameters of [**`admin.site.register(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.register) are a model, or iterable of models; and optionally a model admin. Not a string of that model.

You thus should pass a reference to the `UserProfileInfo`, *not* a *string* that contains that name.

Like:

```
# app/admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from basic_app.models import UserProfileInfo

# an identifier, not a string
admin.site.register(UserProfileInfo)
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to wrap model with string just type model name in `admin.py`

```
Admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from basic_app.models import UserProfileInfo


# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(UserProfileInfo)
```